# how to gat a value from an array which contain in an object and object already in an array while using json response?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios6

```
[
{
  "result": 1,
  "max_qty": "10",
  "msg": [
    {
      "product_id": "39",
      "product_name": "Cabbage",
      "product_price": "18",
      "product_image": "product/39.jpg",
      "product_description": "Fresh Cabbage",
      "product_category": "1",
      "product_qty": [
        {
          "quantity_id": "3",
          "quantity_name": "500 gm",
          "value": "500",
          "quantity_status": "1"
        },
        {
          "quantity_id": "4",
          "quantity_name": "1 Kg",
          "value": "1000",
          "quantity_status": "1"
        }
```

In this "msg" which is an array and contains value in form of object but "product_qty" again an array which is under the object,now how can i fetch the elements value of product_qty ][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yPpT.png)

Comment: let me know if it is working.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Updated Code:

NSDictionary *mainDic = [arrResponse objectAtIndex:0];

NSArray *arrMsg = [mainDic valueForKey:@"msg"];

for (NSDictionary *dicSub in arrMsg) {

NSArray *arrProdQuality = [dicSub valueForKey:@"product_qty"];

for (NSDictionary *dicQuality in arrProdQuality) {

NSLog(@"quantity_name %@",[dicQuality valueForKey:@"quantity_name"]);

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just used this
if([array containsObject dict])
{
    `already in your array`
}
else
{
    `not in your array`
}

Answer (score -1):

You need to fetch key value like this:

```
NSDictionary *dictProducts =  array[0]; // From Main Array.
NSArray *allProduct = dictProducts[@"msg"]; // Form Dictionary.
NSDictionary *firstProduct = allProduct[0];
NSLog(@"Product Qty : %@", firstProduct[@"product_qty"]); // Here you can get product_qty array.
```

Hope this will helps.